# Graph collaboration tool and adjacency list generation

Tags: graph, saas, adjacency-list, graph-visualization

I'm looking for an online tools where me and my team could collaborate on creating graphs.

The purpose is to bind related words, and generate the adjacency list. For example,

```
Foo----Bar----Brool
        |_____Lol
```

will generate the following list :

```
Foo,[Bar]
Bar,[Foo,Brool,Lol]
Brool,[Bar]
Lol,[Bar]
```

The idea is to allow people to collaborate simply using graph visualization, without diving through the adjacency list directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is one service wchich I believe is going to be designed to allow people to collaborate on creating a graph. It is [Graph Commons](http://graphcommons.com/). Site slogan says:

  > Collaborative 'network mapping' platform and knowledge base of relationships

  Unfortunately at the moment you can only sign up for beta invitation on the website. And from the website it is not clear what the creation/editing mechanism would be.
- You could use [yfiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_web_about.html) library to build a graph editor online, but I've never used it and I don't know if you can manage multimple sessions (hence allowing direct collaboration). But, for instance, if you use [graphity](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_graphity_about.html), which is an implementation of yfiles flex library, and save a file on dropbox, then each collaborator has access to that file, and you can set up a rudimentary collaboration graph tool. Maybe.
- It would be great to have tools like [LucidChart](https://www.lucidchart.com/) or [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/), but they don't allow to export a graph file (e.g. graphML from which you can then have an edgelist with some other programs like [Gephi](https://gephi.github.io/)). Those tools only allow you to export images and vectors. Draw.io exports xml, but not graphML.
- I believe [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us/) let you edit your graph. Again, I've never used it, I don't know if you can manage multiple sessions > collaboration. But I would check it out. **Edit**: [Linkurious enterprise](http://linkurio.us/pricing/) edition (see pricing) is desegned to handle multiple user sessions.
- What about building something with [vis.js](http://visjs.org/docs/index.html)? The library has the ability to «listen for changes in the data» using a DataSet component. Have a look at [this example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/16_dynamic_data.html).

I'm sorry if I don't have any real answer, but since your question is very interesting in these days, and the right tools would come out sooner or later (if it doesn't exists), I wanted to share these thoughts. I hope they can help. Please post when you find a solution!